# Sorting integer field in ArcGIS Modelbuilder and using smallest value as variable for tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3

I have to populate a new field using a formula containing the smallest value of an existing field.

As this is a small part of a larger model I am wondering which is the most efficient method.

My thoughts are as follows:

1. Sort the field ascending and somehow use the top value
   or
2. Use a formula to search for the smallest integer greater than zero and use this value as a variable?

Which method would be most viable with ModelBuilder from ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop?

Comment: What license level?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I would use Summary Statistics to get the minimum value into a one row table, and then use the Get Field Value (Model Only tool) to read that row and field.

A very similar technique is described in [Examples of using Model Only tools in ModelBuilder](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-model-only-tools-in-modelbuilder.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C6447050F5D34A8DA2121D405EC52F69).